# Срабатывает одно условие Python и не выводит else

Tags: python, if

при входных данных 10, 20, -100, -50 должно вывести пустое множество, но по каким то причинам в консоли получаю код 0, не могу понять в чем дело

```
a1 = int(input())
b1 = int(input())
a2 = int(input())
b2 = int(input())

if (a1 < (b2 and a2)):
    if (b1 > (a2 and b2)):
        print(a2, b2)
    if (a2 < b1) and (b1 == b2):
        print(a2,b2)
    if (a1==a2 and b1==b2):
        print(a2, b2)

elif (a2 == a1):
    if (b2 > (b1 and a1)):
        print(a1, b1)
elif (b1 == b2):
    if (a2 < (a1 and b1)):
        print(a1, b1)
elif (a2 < a1 > b1 and b2):
    if (a2 and a1 < b1 < b2):
        print(a1, b1)

elif ((a1 and a2) < b1 < b2):
    if a1 < a2 > (b1 and b2):
        print(a2, b1)
elif (a2 and a1) < b2 < b1:
    if a2 < a1 < (b2 and b1):
        print(a1, b2)
elif (a2 > a1) and (b2 > b1):
    if (b1==a2):
        print(a2)
elif (a1 > a2 ) and (b1 > b2):
    if (a1==b2):
        print(a1)
else:
    print('пустое множество')
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень странные условия...

Вот это к, примеру.

```
if (a1 < (b2 and a2))
```

Есть подозрение, что закладывалась логика **если a1 меньше b2 и меньше a2**

Но на самом деле оно работает не так.

Здесь получается что сначала выполняется операция в скобках. Но по сути **a and b** в результате возвращает **a**.

Если нужно условие **если a1 меньше b2 и меньше a2**, то надо писать

```
if (a1 < b2 and a1 < a2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ! Просто переписал полностью код в итоге, ибо самому не особо понятно было, что написал xD

Answer (score 2):

у вас срабатывает последнее условие

```
elif (a1 > a2) and (b1 > b2):
```

Дальше идёт проверка

```
if a1 == b2:
```

У вас a1 = 10, b2 = -50. Поэтому программа выдаёт ничего

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ! Просто переписал полностью код в итоге, ибо самому не особо понятно было, что написал xD